# Mixing different digital cameras in the same movie

Tags: mixing

For my next movie, I want to have a second camera to record a different angle. My main camera is a mid-range Canon DSLR and I was planning to buy a second, cheaper DSLR. Would it be possible to see the difference between the two cameras in the finished movie? I'm guessing that the number of megapixels would make a difference if they are not the same.

Would a Nikon 1 or Canon Powershot or equivalent higher-end compact work?

Answer (score 1):

HD 1080 video is only 2 megapixels, so the camera full size rating would not be an issue for video.  You have to put all of the video clips together in a video editor of course, which should not any issue.  I would shoot with both cameras at the same settings, like 30p.

There is always a possibly of slight color/tint differences in two cameras.  Probably not noticeable on different scenes, but different views of the same scene possibly might notice? The video editor should allow correction in some degree even it does show.

Answer (score 0):

The single parameter I would care most is the frame rate. Make sure there are no odd frame conversions that produce hiccups or excessive smear or ghosting. So, either shoot at the same frame rate, or convert in a way to avoid visible artefacts. Everything else is not important. Of course, one can see the difference between shallow-DOF shot from a DSLR and a long-DOF shot from a smartphone, but this is fine as long as you stick to some convention, say shallow-DOF for interviews and long-DOF for B-shots. Inconsistent sound and color would irritate a viewer more than inconsistent resolution.

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely possible to see the difference between two cameras, even the same model! The trick is mainly getting them to match together in post production. For example Black Swan was famously shot on an Arri Alexa, with some scenes shot on a Cannon DSLR. So yes it is definitely possible - but if you read up on the production notes you'll see that they did quite a bit of post-work to get the images to line up.

As mentioned frame rate is key (you won't even be able to cleanly edit two different frame rates on one timeline) but so are many other things. You'll want to match shutter speed, white balance and ideally ISO. Though realize that matching these settings does not mean you'll get the same image across cameras, color in particular (white balance) will not match exactly and that's where color correction will come in. But given you roughly match your settings, and spend a bit of time tweaking color you can get something that cuts perfectly without too much worry.

And to answer your question about cheaper point-and-shoot cameras I would say absolutely not. Not if you are half-serious about your production.